# What is the efficient way to reach the Star Metal and Black Ice zone?

Tags: conan-exiles

In Conan Exiles the map is divided in a different biomes with a different climate - from hot desert to icebergs. The most advanced minerals - Star Metal, obsidian, gold and black ice - are only available in the frozen areas on the north of the map.

However, when I am trying to reach that area, I am immediately struck by cold, even while I am wearing the  [Winter's Majesty armor](https://conanexiles.fandom.com/wiki/Winter%27s_Majesty) set, which gives in total (at least according to wiki) 10 bars protection from cold. Of course, the natural answer would be "get a better cold-resistant armor", but to get something epic like the Godbreaker set (40 bars in cold resistance) I need access to Star Metal and Black Ice, but as I've mentioned, I can't reach it without better armor. Catch-22.

I know that you can drink alcohol to warm yourself up, but that ends with getting drunk (and having hangover), not mentioning that it doesn't last long.

So what is the efficient way of reaching the star metal and black ice area?